# (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>') on http Request to Api

Tags: flutter

Below code return type'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fewis/models/vacancy.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class VacancyApi {
  static Future<List<VacancyModel>> getVacancy() async {
    String url = "https://digitalfewis.com/api/vacany_information";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // return vacancyModelFromJson(response.body);
        List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        return jsonResponse
            .map((data) => new VacancyModel.fromJson(data))
            .toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Slow Network Connection');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

[[I was fetching Data from Api and i have made Json Model class but when i tried to convert the json to list it gives me an error  'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj3Hk.png)

Comment: Next time Adding the question also add which API you are hitting and what is the response you get so we can understand better. The answer given by @Rahul is right.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is List of List.

You might want to do

```
List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
if(jsonResponse.isNotEmpty) {
    List vacanciesJson = jsonResponse[0];
    return vacanciesJson
            .map((data) => VacancyModel.fromJson(data))
            .toList();
}
```